# Problema pasando valor de un atributo de clase a un método de la misma clase

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Estoy teniendo un problema extremadamente básico y no consigo solucionarlo, básicamente he creado una clase con un constructor donde inicializo los atributos de la clase a su valor por defecto y he creado un listener, de manera que cuando levanto la tecla espacio llame a la funcion "crono" para empezar un cronometro.

El problema es que dentro de la funcion crono, cuando llamo a this.milisegundos++ para sumarle un milisegundo segun el debugger this.milisegundos es NaN por lo que por alguna razon el this no me esta funcionando.

Creo que es relevante decir que la funcion crono es llamada desde la funcion startStop() mediante el window.setInterval para asi esperar 10 milisegundos entre cada incremento.

Aqui dejo el codigo necesario para ver el error:

```
export class AppCronometroComponent {
    public segundos: any;
    public minutos: any;
    public milisegundos: any;
    public intervalo = null;
    public accion: String;
    public flag: Number;
    public listaTiempos: Array<String>;
    constructor() {
        this.segundos = 0;
        this.minutos = 0;
        this.milisegundos = 0;
        this.intervalo = null;
        this.accion = 'parado';
        this.flag = 0;
        this.listaTiempos = [];
    }
    @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
    keyEvent(e: KeyboardEvent) {
        const code = e.keyCode;
        if (this.accion === 'parado' && this.flag === 0) {
            if (code === 32) {
                this.startStop();
            }
        } else if (this.accion === 'activo') {
            if (code === 13) {
                this.startStop();
                this.flag = 1;
            }
        } else if (this.accion === 'parado' && this.flag === 1) {
            if (code === 32) {
                this.reset();
                this.flag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    crono() {
      this.milisegundos++;
      if (this.segundos === 59 && this.milisegundos === 99) {
        this.milisegundos = 0;
        this.segundos = 0;
        this.minutos++;
      } else
      if (this.milisegundos === 99) {
        this.milisegundos = 0;
        this.segundos++;
      }

      document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = this.minutos + ':' + 
      this.segundos + ':' + this.milisegundos;
      }
    startStop() {
        if (this.accion === 'parado') {
           this.intervalo = window.setInterval(this.crono, 10);
           this.accion = 'activo';

       } else {
           window.clearInterval(this.intervalo);
           this.accion = 'parado';
           this.ultimoTiempo();
           this.listaTiempos.push(this.minutos + ':' + this.segundos + ':' + 
           this.milisegundos);
           this.media5();
           this.media25();
           this.media100();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes llamar a tu función de la siguiente manera:

```
setInterval(this.crono.bind(this), 10);
```

Lo anterior seria algo asi:

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.milisegundios++;
}, 10);
```

Y esto también funcionaria, ya que la funcion que se crea y se ejecuta dentro del `setInterval` se encuentra en el mismo contexto que tu variable contadora.

Con esto permites que la función se ejecute en el mismo contexto (y asi poder acceder a la variable milisegundos). La razón de porque recibes un NaN cada vez que se ejecuta es porque en el contexto en el cual se ejecuta cuando la llamas como `this.crono` la variable `milisegundos` no se encuentra definida.